# CodeIgniter migrate from windows to linux page not found

Tags: php, apache, codeigniter, ubuntu, virtualbox

Well, I have a ubuntu server installed on virtual box running on windows 7.
The virtual machine has 2 adapters set, adapter 1 is host-only meanwhile adapter 2 is NAT. In the NAT adapter, I set up the forwarding port to open the port to outside of the network. So whenever the ip address of the host is typed on browser it will be forwarded to guest ip (Ubuntu server which host a web app). I have a codeigniter folder under /var/www/ and I changed the DocumentRoot in /etc/apache2/sites-available/000-default.conf from /var/www/html to /var/www/codeigniter
Before changing the config file I can access the starting page index.php in /var/www/html from host's browser however when I changed the DocumentRoot to /var/www/codeigniter and typed the ip on host's browser it said the page was not found on the server when it's clearly there.

Note that : the codeigniter origin was from host pc (Windows 7) and I moved to Ubuntu. When downloading the new codeigniter files from ellislab's website it works fine. but it doesnt work with the old codeigniter file from windows

how can I solve this problem ?
Do I need to do something with the virtual host on windows ?

Comment: rewrite pointing at a script which doesn't exist? "404" errors are **NOT** a network problem.

Comment: I think it's because I copied the folder from host (windows 7) to guest (ubuntu server). Because when I downloaded the new codeigniter file from ellislab's website and point the DocumentRoot to the new codeigniter folder, everything is fine.

Comment: Is the folder named 'codeigniter' or 'CodeIgniter'; specifically is the case you are using for the directory completely correct?

Comment: that is not the case. I think because of the dependency (I guess). Because that folder with its files I copied it from windows 7 (host) to Ubuntu server (guest). It works fine with the new downloaded codeigniter from ellislab but not the old one copied from windows